# Practice problem on ACTEX book

Tags: probability, statistics

There are 12 mathematics faculty at School University. Five are old, nine are bad teachers , and there are three old bad teachers. How many young good teachers are there?

I have encountered similar problem twice in the book.

The other one is: A college class consists of 32 students of which 17 students are engineering majors, and 13 students are female. There are 8 male engineering students in the class. What is the probability that a person chosen at random from this class is a female engineering major?

The answer to the first is 1 and second is .28125 which is not even closet to what i got. I am struggling on whether old bad teacher mean old given bad or vice versa. Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: what did you try so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking at the problem in a much to complicated matter. (no need for conditional probability)

For the first one, the following schematic should be enough.
Start by filling in the old and bad teachers, then fill in the remaining.

Since 1 person is not in the diagram, this one person is not old and not bad which makes the person a young and good teacher.

[image: Old and bad teachers]

The second problem can be resolved in the same way, just use the fact that when 13 student are female, 19 must be male.

Then by the same reasoning you get the following venn-diagram. The remaning probability is easy to calculate then: 
$$\mathcal{P}(\text{female and eng}) = \dfrac{9}{32} = 0.28125$$

[image: male and eng]

Comment: Thank you! I am confused on the kind of problems to use conditional probability. I knew male and engineering would mean intersection. However, I was not aware that male engineering would mean the same thing. I guess I need to look more into conditional probability to grasp the concept.

Answer (score 1):

For your first question, it is important to see that there are old teachers who are also bad. So we should try to find out how much this number is first. 
 Let A be the set of old teachers and let B be the set of bad teachers. Then the old and bad teachers are in the set $A\cap B$. 
 The number of old and bad teachers are $n(A\cap B) = 3$ 
 We are told that the number of old teachers is 5. so $n(A) = 5$. Note that this also includes the old and bad teachers. Similarly, the number of bad teachers is 9. So $n(B) = 9$. Again, this includes the old and bad teachers. 
 When you count the total number of old teachers and the number of bad teachers, you add $n(A)$ to $n(B)$ and subtract $n(A\cap B)$ because you don't want to count the number of teachers who are both old & bad twice.  This is 5 + 9 - 3 = 11. 
 As the total number of teachers in the university is 12, we have 1 young and good teacher.